# BluePrism: how to invoke javascript function when clicking on an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, blueprism, rpa

I want to use a JS function that will be called when an HTML element is clicked. In the navigate properties of my navigate stage, I can choose the HTML element, and select "Invoke Javascript function" as my action, this takes 2 inputs: the function name, and the arguments. Where do I write the function itself?

Comment: At the buttom of the Navigate Stage, search for Properties maybe there you will find things you search.

But, If you can click the element why do you even want to call JS function from BP level? Just click the damm thing :)

Comment: haha, I just want to be able to harness the full capability of BP. I am new to BP so I want to learn how to add some code to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a application modeller to spy the whole window so path is /HTML.(Need to be a HTML element as type) Then use a navigation step and choose "Insert Javascript fragment".

This way you can invoke your JS and then click the button afterwards in BP.